# create img tag only if image exists without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I am trying to create a webpage with a slideshow. The images for the slideshow are stored locally on the machine and are numbered sequentially.

The number of images stored in the directory change every month, so I need to detect how many images there are in the folder and then create the corresponding img tags.

Currently, I have hard coded the value. I know this is possible via server side help but this machine is a test machine and I cannot setup a server on it.

Is there a way to detect the number of images and then create the img tags?

The code I have currently:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="cycle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var image_path = "../slideshow/Slide";
            for(j=1; j < 65; j++){
                var imgEl = $('<img id="slideshow-image">');
                imgEl.attr('src', image_path+j+".PNG");
                imgEl.appendTo('.slideImage'); 
            }
            $('.slideImage').cycle({ 
                fx:      'fade', 
                speed:    1000, 
                timeout:  10000,
                fit: 1
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex-column">
            <section>
                <div class="slideImage">

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <nav>

        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot setup e.g WAMP? Javascript cannot have access to local folder/file without user interaction

Comment: No, cant setup a server on the machine. I know JS cant have access to local files but I was thinking along the lines of checking if the image loads or gives an error? But I am not sure how to do this